# If all of LATE (Local Average Treatment Effect) assumptions is satisfied?

Tags: econometrics

I would like to know intuitive and specific interpretation of LATE. 
If all the assumptions for LATE is satisfied, we can say that the Instrument Variable (IV) has an effect to estimate X on Y. Also, LATE provides a consistent estimate of the average treatment effect "only" for a subgroup of the population (Compliers). It does not measure the effect of the treatment or everyone (ATE).

Is there more things to be added? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This feels like a homework question

Comment: I would definitely agree with you, if I were a student.

Comment: I'll give you the benefit of the doubt then.

Your understanding of LATE seems quite correct. We're talking about the effect of treatment not for the population as a whole, but for the group that was assigned to treatment. This is somewhat straightforward to estimate in some contexts, such as when there's perfect enforcement of the treatment assignment rule, but not so much in others.